# Standalone for system integrating netbeans, tomcat and xampp

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, system, xampp

My problem is that i dont know how to create a standalone for a project that i have on netbeans. My project is a selling system where a seller registers items that customers want to buy, and to do this i use netbeans, tomcat and mysql on xampp. I want to know if there is a simple program to create a standalone that integrates all these elements, or is there a way to do it on netbeans. Any clue, hint or suggestion will be much appreciated

Comment: A stand-alone what? Installer? Application?

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example for embedding Tomcat 7 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735676/is-it-possible-to-do-an-embedded-java-servlet-code-like-using-libraries-jetty/9738966#9738966). You can't really add Xampp to a java programm, but have a look at the [MySQL Connector/MXJ](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/mxj/) this will do the trick.

Fianlly make a startup class and first run MySQL and then Tomcat.